# Breaking \underbrace over two lines

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

How can I have something like the following in LaTeX?

```
\begin{align}

\underbrace{equation1 \\ (line break) equation 2}_{text}

\end{align}
```

The problem is the line break.

I don't seem to find any solution online.

Comment: You shouldn't leave blank lines in `\begin{align}...\end{align}`, but this is not the issue.

Comment: You can use `\parbox` inside the `\underbrace`. Inside the `parbox` you can use `\\ `.

Comment: @Skillmon since the material is probably math, might be better to use the `aligned` env inside the `\underbrace` instead of `\parbox`

Comment: @daleif yeah, you're right. Didn't consider that.

Answer (score 3):

As daleif and I said, you should use an environment allowing linebreaks inside the `\underbrace`. If it's just going to be text `\parbox` or similar commands are fine. If it's going to be math, you should use an environment such as `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \underbrace{\begin{aligned}&equation1 \\ &(line break) equation 2\end{aligned}}_{text}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```